# Get attribute from button to node using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I'm simply trying to get the name of a clicked button to my node server and am stuck on something small. If I have something like this in node:

```
app.get('/someUrl', function(req, res) {

    console.log(req.body.name);

});
```

And my jQuery/ajax looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    buttonName(this.name);
  });
});

function buttonName(name) {
  $.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: '/someUrl',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {'name' : name }
 })
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using `body-parser` in node and have -

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: Did you try using the same case on the route and the ajax call? Does the console log anything at all? Have you checked that the ajax call doesn't have any errors etc ?

Comment: Sorry, fixed the url case. It was just filler. Yes, cases are all the same. Is there are error in the ajax above? It seems to work. `undefined` is logged to the console.

Comment: Does your button have a name attribute? I normally pass in the event object to a handler and you can call e.target...

Comment: Yes, it has the name attribute.

Comment: So if you log `name` in the `buttonName` function, it gives you the actual name, not `undefined`? Note that `name` is not a very good name for a variable.

Comment: Yes. Shows up there, but  not in req.body.

Comment: Have you tried passing the event to the handler? 
    ```$('button').click(function(evt) {
        console.log($(evt.target).attr('name))
    })```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you correctly, you just need the name (text) of a button. In that case, you can directly use event target that triggered the event in jquery. and then parse your button text from it. See below code snippet for example. I hope that solves your problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function(e) {
    alert($(e.target).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addElem">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Parse as in `jQuery.parseJSON()`? How do you make `name` show up in `req.body` on the server side?

Comment: If you want to parse on the server side, may be you need to look at cheeriojs library. This snippet parses only client side.

Comment: A library simply to pass the `name` attribute to a node get request? There must be an easy way to do this.